# Compare two dfs and print the values that are not present in one

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, merge

I have two data frames and I want to compare both and print the values that are not present in df1.
example:

```
df1 = |id|check_column1|
      |21|abc|
      |21||bcd|
      |22|hqo|
      |22|hsd|
      |23|mno|

df2 = 

|id|check_column1|
      |21|abc|
      |22|hqo|
      |23|xyz|
```

i want output as

```
|id|check_column1|chack_colum2|
|23|mno|xyz|
```

i dont want the output to include  21-bcd and 22-hsd whose values are already present in df1. Means for the same id if 2 values are there in df1 and 1 is reflected in df2 i dont wanna consider that id for miss match.

```
df = pd.merge(df1,df2,left_on =['id',df1.groupby('id').cumcount()], right_on = ['id',df2.groupby('id').cumcount()] )
```

but this gives all the miss match I want only that is completely different from each other in both the tables

Answer (score 0):

Consider this setup:

```py
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame(
    {"id": [21, 21, 22, 22, 23], "check_column1": ["abc", "bcd", "hqo", "hsd", "mno"]}
)
#    id check_column1
# 0  21           abc
# 1  21           bcd
# 2  22           hqo
# 3  22           hsd
# 4  23           mno
df2 = pd.DataFrame(
    {"id": [21, 22, 23, 23], "check_column1": ["abc", "hqo", "xyz", "www"]}
)
#    id check_column1
# 0  21           abc
# 1  22           hqo
# 2  23           xyz
# 3  23           www
```

How about creating a `set` per `id`, per dataframe, and then computing the set differences between the dataframes for the corresponding ids? Like so:

```py
g1 = df1.groupby("id").agg(set)
g2 = df2.groupby("id").agg(set)
diffs = pd.concat([g1 - g2, g2 - g1], axis=1)
diffs.columns = ["check_column1", "check_column2"]
#    check_column1 check_column2
# id                            
# 21         {bcd}            {}
# 22         {hsd}            {}
# 23         {mno}    {xyz, www}
```

This allows selecting only the rows where there is some value in `df2` that is not in `df1`:

```py
df = diffs[diffs["check_column2"] != set()]
#    check_column1 check_column2
# id                            
# 23         {mno}    {xyz, www}
```